# How to add custom script to plank (dock) in Elementary OS Freya

Tags: shell-script, elementary-os, pantheon

I am using Elementary OS Freya.
I want to add custom bash script to plank (dock).

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 5):

Create a `.desktop` file in your `~/.local/share/applications` folder for the script (or in `usr/share/applications` for system wide access). E.g.:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My bash script
Comment=bash script to do custom stuff
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/bash/script %U
Icon=/path/to/some/fancy/icon
Terminal=false (or true)
Categories=Other;
```

It will show up in the `Other` category for slingshot. Run it and then select "Keep in dock" when it is running.

Comment: you can also drag & drop icons from slingshot to plank, without running them ;)

Answer (score -2):

to save the `.desktop` file you have to add in Terminal:

```
sudo chmod 777 programName.desktop
```